# Update variable in main loop after g_callback GTK+ C

Tags: c, callback, gtk, gtk2

I would like to update the modification done to a pointer variable in a g_callback but I don't know how, could you help me please ? (I'm a totally newbie with GTK+ and C language...)

```
void modify_string(char *str)
{
  char *new_str = "Something new";
  str = new_str;
}

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
  char *str = NULL;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  GtkWidget *screen = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  init_main_window(screen);
  GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Open");

  /* ... */

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(screen), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(modify_string), str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  gtk_main();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is that it prints "(null)" instead of "Something new", do you have any idea to update my string please?

EDIT: I didn't understood that, thanks!

Comment: The `printf()` is called before your GUI ever runs, so you see the initial value of `str` instead. You will need to rework your program logic around events (and possibly idle callbacks).

Comment: I'm going to add, it'll be more "safier" to use GString. GString can take care of the space you need by adding more string to the buffer. And yes, you can get string (gchar) out of GString.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You aren't allocating any space for new_str.  And you are assigning a local variable to str, which is lost when the routine finishes and the scope is lost.  Try writing a routine which fixes these two problems.